# Why is Dokku always redirecting to default app?

Tags: asp.net, docker, dokku

I'm publishing an ASP.NET 5 app to Dokku using Git. Everything seems to succeed and the final line of output is the URL that the app resides at. However, when I visit that URL, I'm taken to a demo app that I previously published to check that everything was working. Why is this?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
COPY . ./foo/
WORKDIR /foo
RUN dotnet publish -c release -o /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Foo.dll"]
```

Comment: Are you setting `ASPNETCORE_URLS`?

Comment: @abdusco I tried doing that and it didn't make any discernable difference. I then tried using it in combination with `EXPOSE` and it just broke things even more (I started getting an error about ASP.NET being unable to find an SSL certificate).

Comment: Expose only HTTP (`ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+"`) and terminate SSL with a reverse proxy (nginx/caddy), which dokku sets it up for you if I'm not mistaken. (Also remember to enable forwarded headers middleware)

Comment: I added `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS="http://+"` to my Dockerfile and it didn't make any difference. I've also tried deleting the demo app that I was getting redirected to and now, instead, the connection fails completely.

Comment: How does the demo app tie into all this? How is it related to dokku?

Comment: It was the first one I published and I'd get redirected to it when I visited the explicit URL for it, as well as the subdomain I'm hosting Dokku on (i.e. demoapp.subdomain.example.net and subdomain.example.net), although based on my experience it seems I get redirected to it for literally everything under *.subdomain.example.net.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I wasn't specifying a protocol and so Firefox was defaulting to HTTPS, which I hadn't set up, and so the connection was refused.

After explicitly specifying HTTP, my site sprang to life. Getting HTTPS working was pretty straightforward using the Dokku [letsencrypt](https://github.com/dokku/dokku-letsencrypt) plugin.

I've also added `ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000` to my Dockerfile.